# Regarding Magento 2.1.7 "Service Temporarily Unavailable" error

Tags: magento-2.1, php, error, mamp

Problem is it does not take me to the admin panel. When I go to Magento through localhost it shows error message "**Service Temporarily Unavailable**".

Magento 2.1.7 is successfully installed on the database and I added Magento to the htdocs folder on Mac.

Comment: Please mention Magento version you have installed, so that other users can answer for that particular Magento version.

Comment: hi Mohit
I have installed Magento 2.1.7

Comment: In my opinion, answer from @vinod-kumar is correct. Please check /var/log folder for the exception if you can't find maintenance.flag file.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a file called maintenance.flag and if so delete it.

> Magento 1.x : maintenance.flag file is in : magento root directory
>
> Magento 2.x : maintenance.flag file is in : var folder

When Magento is performing certain tasks it temporarily creates this file. Magento checks for its existence and if it's there will send users to the page you described.

Comment: Hi vinod
 I checked I found about maintenance files like maintenance.php etc. but  i cannot find maintenance.flag file

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove the following file in magento root directory,

```
maintenance.flag
```

Comment: Hi Pasupathi
 I checked I found about 20 maintenance files like maintenance.php etc. but  i cannot find maintenance.flag file

Comment: If maintenance.flag file was not found means follow this instructions.clear the cache and open the project in private window and check it now.Then check what error shows in home page.

Comment: I am totally new to this. can you please explain in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly change between Magento 1 and 2 in the maintenance mode because these are the locations of the maintenance flags

> Magento 1 = in the root
>
> Magento 2 = in the var folder

The strangest thing is that in Magento 2 the file is a **hidden** file

> **.maintenance.flag**

**NOTE :** The maintenance file in Magento 2 is a hidden file and will only be listed when you use ls -la

Comment: The maintenance file in Magento 2 is a hidden file and will only be listed when you use ls -la